# Facebook Dialog Sharing issue with SDK in android(#100 invalid fbid)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am facing one issue in publishing post via facebook app using sdk in android.
When I am trying to post something, it gives me toast message like"(#100) invalid fbid". and Log is printed as : Error: com.facebook.FacebookException: Error publishing message.

*Please note:* I have added Publish Permission,My FB App is visible to all Users and most Importantly,I have made a demo using same app id,package name and all and it is working there,but when I am merging that code in app,It always ends up in the error.

So,What could be the cause?Because same code,same fb app id is working fine in separate app,but not working when merged in the application.
Please suggest what should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED.There was mistake in manifest.xml...We should write android:value="app_id".I have written android:resource="app_id"..So it was error of class casting between Integer and String.